# Perl regex combining capture groups & nth string

Tags: regex, perl

I have files like the following:

```
<div title="alpha" Mauris eu justo sed nisi aliquet blandit. <span name="ll">beta</span> Fusce in pharetra nisi. <span name="ll">gamma</span> Aliquam vehicula imperdiet turpis et rhoncus. <span name="ll">delta</span> Donec faucibus augue quis neque dictum, at rutrum dolor placerat.</div>
```

I try to get the content of nth `name="ll"` attribute in place of `title=` content while preserving the order of the rest.

For example, the 2nd `name="ll"` would get me:

```
<div title="gamma" Mauris eu justo sed nisi aliquet blandit. <span name="ll">beta</span> Fusce in pharetra nisi. Aliquam vehicula imperdiet turpis et rhoncus. <span name="ll">delta</span> Donec faucibus augue quis neque dictum, at rutrum dolor placerat.</div>
```

Etcetera.

---

My try:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -w -e 's/(title=)"?[^"\s]*"?(.*)((?:.*?\h+class="ll">){1}.*?)\h+class="ll">"?([^"\s]+)"?(<.*)/$1"$3"$2$4/' \{\} \;
```

Where do I make the mistake?

Comment: You know that you should never give the same name to multiple elements?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing everything in one substitution, proceed in steps:

```
perl -wpe '$n = 2;
           @m = /<span name="ll">([^<]+)/g;
           s/title="[^"]+"/title="$m[$n-1]"/;
           s:<span name="ll">\Q$m[$n-1]\E</span> ::;'
```

i.e.

1. extract all the strings that can be moved;
2. replace the title by the wanted string;
3. remove the span containing the wanted string.

Answer (score 2):

This perl solution should work for you:

```bash
# matching 2nd <span name="ll">
perl -pe 's~(title=)"?[^"\s]*"?((?:.*?\h+<span name="ll">){1}.*?)\h+<span name="ll">([^<]+)</span>~$1"$3"$2~' file

<div title="gamma" Mauris eu justo sed nisi aliquet blandit. <span name="ll">beta</span> Fusce in pharetra nisi. Aliquam vehicula imperdiet turpis et rhoncus. <span name="ll">delta</span> Donec faucibus augue quis neque dictum, at rutrum dolor placerat.</div>

# matching 3rd <span name="ll">
perl -pe 's~(title=)"?[^"\s]*"?((?:.*?\h+<span name="ll">){2}.*?)\h+<span name="ll">([^<]+)</span>~$1"$3"$2~' file

<div title="delta" Mauris eu justo sed nisi aliquet blandit. <span name="ll">beta</span> Fusce in pharetra nisi. <span name="ll">gamma</span> Aliquam vehicula imperdiet turpis et rhoncus. Donec faucibus augue quis neque dictum, at rutrum dolor placerat.</div>
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

**Explanation:**

- `(title=)`: Match `title=` and capture in group #1
- `"?[^"\s]+"?`: Match an *optionally* quoted non-space string
- `(`: Start capture group #2

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `.*?`: Match any text (lazy match)
    - `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
    - `<span name="ll">`: Match text `<span name="ll">`
  - `){1}`: End non-capture group and repeat this group `{1}` times
  - `.*?`: Match any text (lazy match)
- `)`: End capture group #2
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `<span name="ll">`: Match text `<span name="ll">`
- `([^<]+)`: Match 1+ of any char that is not a `>` and capture in group #3
- `</span>`: Match `</span>`
- `$1"$3"$2`: Replacement part